# How bad is this crawlspace sewage spill?

Tags: crawlspace, sewage

We had a sewer back-up that was quickly dealt with but it was enough to drop some sewage water into the crawlspace. It came from underneath one of the bathroom toilets which had wax ring that started leaking water under the intense pressure.

The spill is concentrated in the area under the toilet and did not travel any further. It looks like mostly water, no feces, toilet paper, etc.

How bad is this spill? Could this be easily treated with some garden lime and other DIY methods? Is this spill professional restoration territory?

Thank you[image]

Comment: Your description is confusing. How does a toilet drain ever end up under pressure? It's open to the atmosphere. Just curious.

Comment: @isherwood there was a sewer back-up and the water started leaking from the base of the toilet. The wax ring was done for. Water started to drip down to the crawlspace from the toilet according to the plumber.

Comment: @popham there is no vapor barrier. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: That doesn't sound like "intense pressure". It's just a gravity leak, which is basically _no_ pressure.

Comment: @isherwood what I trying to explain is that the pressure from the sewer back-up removed the seal from the wax ring in the toilet, at which point yes, there was a gravity leak as you described.

Comment: And I'm pointing out that this isn't possible. There's no more pressure with a backup than there is with a plain ol' flush. It's semantics, but understanding is sometimes important.

Comment: @isherwood, a plunger could generate some pressure when opposed by an immovable object. 10# on the plunger handle plus a water surface of 2" diameter implies an upper bound of about 3 psi. Doesn't seem like enough to bust through that wax, but shocks instead of steady pressure can do odd things. If removing the toilet to clear the clog was necessary, then obviously that's how the water spilled.

Comment: @isherwood are you suggesting that the gravity leaks could have come from the flushing of the toilet and not the sewer back-up? There is enough dampness to suggest the water could have come from a few flushes and not a slow gravity leak from a failed wax ring.

Comment: Also, what about the combined pressure of the sewer back-up plus the flushing of the toilet? That would be enough to bust the wax ring.

Comment: No vapor barrier? How is the water still sitting there, then? Or has it subsequently infiltrated into the soil?

Comment: @popham The picture was taken yesterday by the plumber. The spill commenced 4 days ago. I think it was enough water to pool a little bit, as you can see it went up to the foundation of the house. Since then my guess is that it's been drying. The crawlspace is properly vented but not enough time has passed for the water to fully dry.

Comment: @elektrei, especially for a vented crawlspace, that doesn't look like enough water to cause any mold issues as long as there's no wood with water pooled on it. If it has been slow leaking forever, then there could already have been some mold encouragement, but nothing you do with the current water is going to fix that. For the wood sitting on top of the concrete sponge, see [IRC R317.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/IRC2018P4/chapter-3-building-planning/IRC2018P4-Ch03-SecR317.1) to put your mind at ease.

Comment: It certainly could've come from a backup, but _only_ if the backup resulted in the liquid level in the pipes reached the wax ring and not the bowl rim (which obviously you'd have known about). It's a pretty long-shot scenario. You seem confused about how pressure builds in a system. A flush against a backup can only result in pressure equal to the height of the water column, which isn't much at all, plus a tiny bit for momentum. Again, it's an _open_ system.

Comment: @isherwood I have a clip of how the toilet was backing up, the water went up to the base and also made the water from bowl bubble: https://imgur.com/a/ZH1taHS. Does this help explain where the leak is coming from and why?

Comment: That's already quite clear. The only issue is that you've stated "intense pressure", which there was not. The reason the seal leaked is probably due to reverse flow. With the toilet flush, water drops into the pipe through a directed, gravity-driven column. With this backup it gets pushed _around_ the toilet tailpiece. Imagine pouring from a pitcher into a glass, then pushing the glass up around the pitcher. Again... semantics.

Comment: @isherwood if not by using the word pressure how do you explain that when the plumber opened the cap from the sewer access at the street level, a big amount of sewage water started to come out from the access point? Wasn't the water under pressure and found a way to come out as soon as it was given a chance? Or is that momentum? I understand, semantics, here to learn so thanks for your patience.

Comment: @isherwood I also still struggle to understand how the water reached the crawlspace. If the pipes weren't leaking, was all the spill happening around the wax ring and that water gravity fell to the crawlspace?

Comment: Seems like it to me. The sewer point must've been lower than your toilet. Again, if it was under pressure like you describe, your _ceiling_ would've been wet.

Comment: Yes, the sewer point is definitely lower than the toilet that was leaking, about 4 stairs lower.

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat subjective, making it borderline off topic here. It's a matter of your health risk tolerance and the *effects* of the spill, specifically poo stink and framing rot potential.

I would tackle it myself. I'd use a weed sprayer to mist all affected areas with bleach water. I'd remove any soil deemed excessively contaminated. I'd wear protective and disposable clothing while working. I'd use fans and openings to the exterior to ventilate heavily until things are dried out well. Then I'd go on with life. But that's me.

Comment: Someone has a problem with my strategy. Care to share?